# How to make a noisey signal look smooth in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, smoothing

So, I have this jaggedy signal, I wonder if there's some parameter in matplotlib to make its plot smoother.
I've seen TensorBoard having a slider to control smoothness of plots of jaggedy random curves.

[image]

PS: I want some simple code trick, not a fancy signal processing technique.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas to filter your data easily like this:

```py
    import numpy as np

    elements = 100
    noise = np.random.normal(0,10,elements)
    signal = []
    for i in range(elements):
        signal.append(i+noise[i])

    import pandas as pd

    #if you run jupyter-notebook
    %matplotlib inline
    #load data into pandas
    series = pd.Series(signal)
    series.plot()

    #you can filter with rolling mean / median, etc in a window of 5 like:
    filtered_mean = series.rolling(5).mean()
    filtered_mean.plot()

    filtered_median = series.rolling(5).median()
    filtered_median.plot()
```

note : pandas can plot with matplotlib directly, if you start to work with pandas series/dataframes. This can make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

I only know of linear trends with python (with seaborn regplot function).

For something more sophisticated, you will a little bit of signal processing. For instance, you could do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

degree = 10
# Let's say you need a trend line for the points (x,y)
z = np.polyfit(x, y, degree)
p = np.poly1d(z)

plt.plot(x,y,'b')
plt.plot(x,p(x),'r')

plt.show()
```